# how to select into an array in pl/sql?

Tags: sql, plsql

I'm trying to add some ids into an array:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_of_numbers AS VARRAY(10)OF NUMBER(10);

declare
    student_ids array_of_numbers;
begin
    select nrleg BULK COLLECT into student_ids from student where nrleg = 123458;
    FOR i IN 1..student_ids.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(student_ids(i));
    END LOOP;
end;
```

but I get the following errors:

```
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" 
10/4      PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     ( begin case declare end exception exit for goto if loop mod    null pragma raise return select update while with    <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>    <a bind variable> << continue close current delete fetch lock    insert open rollback savepoint set sql execute commit forall    merge pipe purge json_exists json_value json_query    json_object json_array 
Errors: check compiler log
```

Could someone explain what I did wrong?

Comment: Remove DECLARE; it is not to be used in named PL/SQL procedures.

Comment: @Littlefoot but if I remove the declare part I won't have an array to save the data into (?)

Comment: I didn't say to remove the whole section, but the DECLARE keyword.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, blinded by how-knows-what. This is an anonymous PL/SQL block. The only thing that's missing is a slash that terminated the CREATE TYPE statement. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

Some DDL needs to be terminated with a `/`; a type can have a PL/SQL body so this is one of them. To run that all at once as a script do:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE array_of_numbers AS VARRAY(10)OF NUMBER(10);
/

declare
 student_ids array_of_numbers;
begin
select nrleg BULK COLLECT into student_ids from student where nrleg = 123458;
    FOR i IN 1..student_ids.COUNT LOOP
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(student_ids(i));
    END LOOP;
end;
/
```

You don't need the semicolon on the end of the `CREATE` here, but it doesn't hurt; but for some other commands (including other DDL like `create table`) having both would cause it to try to execute the statement twice, which could cause an error.

SQL Developer won't complain about the lack of a `/` after the last PL/SQL block in a script, but other tools will, so it's better to always include that one too.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=77462dfd95fe5cefb4f816cb36c732a5)

---

Incidentally, another way to see the contents of the array in SQL Developer is with a ref cursor:

```
var rc refcursor

declare
  student_ids array_of_numbers;
begin
  select nrleg BULK COLLECT into student_ids from student where nrleg = 123458;
  open :rc for select * from table(student_ids);
end;
/

print rc
```

... but then you might as well just select directly from the table, without any PL/SQL.

Comment: Now I'm trying to print the numbers from the array like this: for i in student_ids.first..student_ids.last loop
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(student_ids(i));
end loop;       but I get this :end loop
Error report -
Unknown Command

Comment: @user14769698 - that error is from the client; so are you trying to do that outside a PL/SQL block? [it works inside one](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0ef315f168ce792b278a677826334f73).

Comment: I added BEGIN and END; but it I get the same thing.

Comment: It's unclear what you're doing (or doing wrong); the fiddle shows that it works if you run it properly.

Comment: Aaah thank you, it worked with the cursor!